# Encode URL parameters in objective c

Tags: objective-c, post, httprequest, urlencode

I am trying to encode a URL request parameter in order to avoid using reserved characters. The main reason for this is that I have to send a POST request to an API that receives a data from an encrypted URL parameter, so I want to avoid sending a request where this parameter has reserved characters. I been searching for some method an I found this.

```
[parameterData stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters: [NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]]
```

But it does not encode all characters.

Comment: URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet